# Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL }

Tags: android

On android 4.4, adb shell, I tried the `android.intent.action.CALL` and meet with Error.

```
root:/ # am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:10010    
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat= tel:10010 }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat= tel:10010 flg=0x10000000 }
```

Do you know the reason why?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I guess you are getting the error because of the lack of permissions. When starting that intent within an app that app needs the CALL_PHONE permission in the manifest

Answer (score 3):

did you put in your manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />` ?

this is a functional example:

```
 String uri = "tel:" + "yourphone".trim() ;
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks all. The problem sovled with permission.